# How to use environment variables defined inside a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I currently have a Makefile that looks something like this:

```
some_process:
    VAR1=1
    VAR2=2

    python3 ./main.py --arg1 /home/user1/something/ \
                      --arg2 $VAR1 \
                      --arg3 $VAR2
```

When I run this code I get the error:

```
main.py: error: argument --arg2: expected one argument
```

I've tried using brackets around `VAR1` and `VAR2`, but I noticed that if I do that then the Makefile doesn't recognize(?) the arguments. I also tried escaping the $ sign (i.e. `$$VAR1`) but this also does not work.

What is the proper way to use a Makefile  for environment variables? Thanks.

### EDIT

Just in case it's unclear from the original question, I'm using the Makefile to replicate what I'd usually do in the command line:

```
user@thing:$ export VAR1=1
user@thing:$ export VAR2=2
user@thing:$ python3 ./main.py --arg1 /home/user1/something --arg2 $VAR1 --arg3 $VAR2
```

Comment: Have you tried like this : `$(VAR1)` ?

Comment: Yes, I have. That's actually what I meant by "brackets." I've tried parentheses and curly brackets and neither work. :(

Comment: Did you tried to export the variables into the makefile?

Comment: @Phantom I actually haven't tried that and I didn't know that was possible. I'll take a look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic problems with the code shown...

```
some_process:
    VAR1=1
    VAR2=2

    python3 ./main.py --arg1 /home/user1/something/ \
                      --arg2 $VAR1 \
                      --arg3 $VAR2
```

Firstly, `make` runs each line from the commands section of a rule in its own shell.  So `VAR1=1` is run in a shell and then, effectively, lost.  Secondly, tokens such as `$VAR1` will be expanded by `make` rather than the shell.  In this case -- because there's no parentheses -- `$VAR1` will be interpreted by `make` as `$(V)AR1`.  That is, the value of the variable `V` followed by the text `AR1`.  You can use `$$` to force `make` to ignore the expansion.

Taking all of the above into account you could try (untested)...

```
some_process:
    VAR1=1; \
    VAR2=2; \
    python3 ./main.py --arg1 /home/user1/something/ \
                      --arg2 $$VAR1 \
                      --arg3 $$VAR2
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as @G.M. pointed out, `make` runs each command in a rule in separate sub-shells; so variable assignments in separate lines won't work. Also beware of the variable reference format. `$(VAR1)` or `${VAR1}` if it needs to be expanded by `make`, `$$VAR1` if it needs to be expanded in a sub-shell.

Having said that, you can define `VAR1` and `VAR2` as `make` variables and [`export`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html) them to make them available for your `some_process` rule.

```
VAR1 := 1
VAR2 := 2

export VAR1 VAR2

some_process:
    python3 ./main.py --arg1 /home/user1/something/ \
        --arg2 $$VAR1 \
        --arg3 $$VAR2
```

This way, you can override the variable values when you invoke the rule if needed.

```sh
$ make some_process VAR2=22
```

By the way, as you're explicitly giving the variables as command line arguments to your python script, they don't need to be `export`ed; so the following should work just fine.

```
VAR1 := 1
VAR2 := 2

some_process:
    python3 ./main.py --arg1 /home/user1/something/ \
        --arg2 $(VAR1) \
        --arg3 $(VAR2)
```

Comment: The very last example here is the one I would consider the most "make-ish" solution.  Plus as an added bonus you can easily change these values without editing your makefile, simply by running `make VAR1=7` etc.